# Selecting ml.net features for grouping strings by a single column

Tags: ml.net

Trying to apply a little AI/ML to a process we currently do manually.
I have a list of approximately 100k company names. Many of those company names refer to the same company but are spelled slightly differently. For example:

- Building and Inspection Co

  - Building & Inspection Company
  - Building Inspection Company
  - The Building and Inspection Company

and so on.
There are probably 20k unique companies in the list.
Is there a way to use ML.NET to give me groupings of like company names? We could then normalize our input data by assigning all those names in each group to a single spelling of the company name.

Thanks for any guidance.

**EDIT**

Assuming that clustering is the ml.net feature to use, however, I'm unsure if this works with an unknown (> 10000) number of clusters.

Comment: Trying SOUNDEX in SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a [clustering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), which is very well described in Wikipedia.

In ML.NET today, we only have one clustering algorithm, K-means.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) notes,

> Most k-means-type algorithms require the number of clusters – k – to be specified in advance, which is considered to be one of the biggest drawbacks of these algorithms.

So yes, it is not very well suited for your problem.

From what I know about clustering, you probably should look into [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) with some distance metric similar to [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) on a word level.

You may or may not be able to find an existing C# library for DBSCAN, but even a naive implementation without any index is probably acceptable for your data size.

I hope that helps.